# Piecewise distribution with assigned probabilities

Tags: statistics, density-function

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d. from the following probability distribution

$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{with probability $p$} \\
\operatorname{Uniform}[0,\theta], & \text{with probability $1-p$}
\end{cases}$$

Assume that $p$ is a known constant in $(0,1)$ and that $\theta>0$ is the parameter of interest.

1) Based only on one observation, $X_1$, find all the unbiased estimators for $\theta$.

2) Write the joint likelihood for $X_1,\dots,X_n$.

So far, I have found the only unbiased estimator to be $\frac{2X_1}{1-p}$. I am struggling with the joint distribution. I originally thought of this as a conditional distribution given a Bernoulli random variable, but I cannot get the joint distribution to work out.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are told the $X_i$ are iid, the joint cdf is
$$ F_{X_1,\ldots,X_n}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \mathbb P(X_1 \le x_1, \ldots, X_n \le x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n F_{X_1}(x_i)$$

Comment: Yes, I do understand it will be the product of the individual distributions. However, I first need to find the form of the distribution of $X_1$. I need to write this in a form that is no longer piecewise and takes into account the probabilities.

Comment: I don't know how you want to write this without "piecewise": $$F_{X_1}(x) = \cases{ 0 & if $x < 0$\cr p + (1-p) x/\theta & if $0 \le x \le \theta$\cr 1 & otherwise}$$

Comment: Thank you Robert, I was able to get this same answer as you working on it this morning, and I think using indicators as exponents I can write it in a way that allows me to find sufficient statistics and everything else that I need. I appreciate your help!